# Why is my new split array element being taken as a non-int value?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, int, digits

My question is regarding the way Python3 handles certain array elements.

Here is my code:

```
def isIPv4(inputStr):

    inputStr.split('.') #splits input into array elements (no periods)
    val = []

    for i in inputStr:
        if not i.isdigit():       #if the element is not a digit (valid to convert to INT).
            return False
        if int(i) >=0 and int(i)<=255:    #element value between 0 and 255.
            val.append(i)
        else:
            return False
        return len(val) == 4              #array has 4 elements ^^
```

The code should let me know if the input is an IPv4 address, meaning for numbers between 0 and 255, separated by periods. Returns True or False.

inputs that work:

```
inputStr: "1.1.1.1a"
inputStr: "0..1.0"
```

For both, my code correctly returns False.

inputs that do not work:

```
inputStr: "172.16.254.1"
inputStr: "0.254.255.0"
```

For these, my code also returns False, while it should return True instead.

As you can see, the program handles the splitting of the dot separated values properly, however, even though '1a' is being correctly thrown out as a non-int, '0' and also '172' are being thrown out.

I realize that '0' and '172' are both strings, so is there something I should know about how the Python3 module handles this data?

Comment: `inputStr.split('.')` returns a list. You didn't store that list. `inputStr` itself is an immutable string and *does not change*.

Comment: Understood; so regex is my best choice here, apparently.

Comment: Why would that be the best choice? I've shown below that your approach can work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inputStr.split('.')` returns a list. You ignored that list altogether. `inputStr` itself is an immutable string and *does not change*.

so `inputStr` stays the original string, and you are testing if each *individual character* is a digit. That fails for the `.` characters.

You need to store the result of the `str.split()` call and test against that:

```
def isIPv4(inputStr):
    parts = inputStr.split('.')

    for part in parts:
        if not part.isdigit():
            return False
        if not (0 <= int(part) <= 255):
            return False
    return len(parts) == 4
```

Note that you don't have to build a new `vals` list either; just test if the split result is the right length.

Comment: This solution is producing the same error, however, knowing that it is a list I am working with instead of an array of strings should be sufficient to take the next step. Thanks.

Comment: @LiquidGodSpeed: I found and corrected a small error, try again.

Comment: I can see that the code is very similar, except for the detail you quickly pointed out. This worked beautifully. Cheers.